# getting the first result per page in elasticsearch results

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I want to get back the title of the first result of each page in a search so that I can display them on the pagination ui. Is there an easy way to do this with ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the search with `"fields" : []` to retrieve a list of all matching document IDs [1], and then do a multi-get request to retrieve the documents including whatever information you need to display them [2].

1. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/fields.html
2. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/multi-get.html